# Why "ld -m --verbose" lists no object files (*.o) for *.a

Tags: c, cross-compiling, ld, glib, xen

I am cross compiling glib. When linking the program objects with option -m elf_x86_64 -lglib-2.0 ,it yields lots of undefined reference that should be defined in glib libraries. So I use the --verbose option and find that ld command cannot list the object files that should be included in glib-2.0.a library.

My link commands and outputs are as follows:

```
ld -r -nostdlib -L/media/wind/lab/xen/xen/xen-4.4.0/stubdom/cross-root-x86_64/x86_64-xen-elf/lib  -m elf_x86_64 \
--verbose /media/wind/lab/xen/xen/xen-4.4.0/stubdom/mini-os-x86_64-vmi/arch/x86/x86_64.o \
......\
-L/media/wind/lab/xen/xen/xen-4.4.0/stubdom/mini-os-x86_64-vmi/arch/x86 -lx86_64  \
-lc -lglib-2.0  -lvmi  -o /media/wind/lab/xen/xen/xen-4.4.0/stubdom/mini-os-x86_64-vmi/mini-os.o
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.22
......
attempt to open /media/wind/lab/xen/xen/xen-4.4.0/stubdom/cross-root-x86_64/x86_64-xen-elf/lib/libglib-2.0.a succeeded
attempt to open /media/wind/lab/xen/xen/xen-4.4.0/stubdom/cross-root-x86_64/x86_64-xen-elf/lib/libvmi.a succeeded   (/media/wind/lab/xen/xen/xen-4.4.0/stubdom/cross-root-x86_64/x86_64-xen-elf/lib/libvmi.a)libvmi_la-accessors.o  (/media/wind/lab/xen/xen/xen-4.4.0/stubdom/cross-root-x86_64/x86_64-xen-elf/lib/libvmi.a)libvmi_la-convenience.o
```

As showed above, although "attempt to open" is succeed for glib-2.0.a, no objects are listed. But all other libraries has their own *.o objects listed normally, such as libvmi.a above. Does anyone know what's wrong in my cross compiling?

Comment: What if you extract content of ".a" by hands, using "ar x path/to/archive"?